# layout is not included in all pages in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing an asp.net mvc4 application with Bootstrap 3 and i've _Layout.cshtml in "Shared" folder , in Views, i've two pages, "Index and "Register" and i've included Layout in both of these Views but It seems that Layout is included in only "Index and not in "Register" View. Following are my Index and Register Views

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2 align="center" class="bg-info">Login</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>UserName : </strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="UserName">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Password</strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>

    </div>
  </div>
    <h2 align="center" class="bg-info">SignIn With Other Services</h2>
</form>
   <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/Home/FacebookLogin">
       <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SignIn with Facebook</button>

    </div>
  </div>
   </form>
 <h2 align="center" class="bg-info">Don't Have an Account?</h2>

   <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/Home/Register">
       <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

    </div>
  </div>
   </form>

![@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<h2 align="center" class="bg-info">Register</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>UserName : </strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="UserName">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="check" value="Check Availability" >
        <h4  class="bg-warning"></h4>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Password</strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="upass" name="upass" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>Retype Password</strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="retype" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check below answer

[Section has been defined but not rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "head"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436101/section-has-been-defined-but-not-rendered-for-the-layout-page-views-shared-l)

Also check for it